# ion-tabs are cutting off when generated apk

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

[image]

Using angular version 9, ionic version 5.
Below is the code for tabs page. Somehow the bottom bar is cutoff in some mobiles and it is not displaying only in some mobiles.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button (click)="tabClicked(1, 'jobs')">
      <ion-icon [style]="selectedTabId == 1 ? 'color: #33c7ff' : ''" name="calendar-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button (click)="tabClicked(2, 'payments')">
      <ion-icon [style]="selectedTabId == 2 ? 'color: #33c7ff' : ''" src="assets/icon/payments.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button (click)="tabClicked(3, 'onewash')">
      <ion-icon [style]="selectedTabId == 3 ? 'color: #33c7ff' : ''" src="assets/icon/mop.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="logout" (click)="logout()">
      <ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Do you have the tabs wrapped in ion-footer? Show full code. Also check your css. there maybe some extra margin or padding thats being added.

Comment: please show full code also your css.